# Are these valid Loop optimizations?

Tags: javascript, c#, optimization, foreach

if i do something like the following, is this considered un-optimal (performance wise)?

```
// Is this optimal?
foreach (var fruit in basket.Fruits())
{
  // ....
}

// What about this?
for (var i = 0; i < basket.Fruits().length; ++i) {
  // ....
}

// Alternate way.
var fruits = basket.Fruits();
foreach (var fruit in fruits) 
{
  // ....
}
```

Im looking for answers applicable for .Net as well as Javascript.

Thank you.

Comment: Create test with 100000 fruits and check time difference in both cases.

Comment: i dont think there would be diffrence. compiler will do such optimization. if you think in first loop have to get Fruits in each iterate. no it does not

Comment: Question is... do you need the fruits on your basket later on?

Comment: You really need to pick one language/environment for this question. Performance is extremely context dependent. Different languages & runtime environments make different optimizations and have different tradeoffs to consider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both would be equally performant. `basket.Fruits()` returns an object and JavaScript will create an iterator for that object.

Another solution would be to use

```
Object.keys(basket.Fruits()).forEach(function(fruit) {
  // ...
});
```

Either way, don't focus on this kind of optimization. JavaScript is fast and there are many automatic optimizations. You should be focusing on making your code as legible as possible. After it's done, if you find a slow part, focus on optimizing just that part.

---

According to your edit, you could store the array's length in a variable in the initialization expression of the loop. Then the predicate expression can compare `i<len` instead of computing array length for each iteration.

```
for (var i=0; len=basket.Fruits().length; i<len; i++) ...
```

Comment: What about something like this: (see edit above).

Comment: Thank you for answering the question succinctly rather than playing "politics".